# add zeros in front to meet string number of 5

Tags: excel, vba

I have values of 120, 136, 7120, 72136. The maximum string length should be 5, how do I go about making 120 "00120" and 136 "00136" etc?

Comment: Single line will work in VBA `Range("A1").Value = "'" & Format(Range("A1").Value, "00000")` and `=TEXT(A1,"00000")` in Excel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Single line will work

- VBA

`Range("A1").Value = "'" & Format(Range("A1").Value, "00000")`

- Excel

`=TEXT(A1,"00000")`

Answer (score 1):

In your simple case you can try something simple like this:

```vb
Sub FiveCharString()

    Dim myStr As String

    myStr = "136"

    If Len(myStr) = 2 Then
        myStr = "000" & myStr
    ElseIf Len(myStr) = 3 Then
        myStr = "00" & myStr
    ElseIf Len(myStr) = 4 Then
        myStr = "0" & myStr
    End If

    Debug.Print myStr

End Sub
```

Returns 00136.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function FillWithZero(number as long, digitCount as long) as string
     FillWithZero = Right(String(digitCount , "0") & number , digitCount)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom number format in your cells.
See [Using a custom number format to display leading zeros](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/help/81518/using-a-custom-number-format-to-display-leading-zeros)
or [Keeping leading zeros and large numbers](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7)

Or `.NumberFormat = "00000"` on your range.

I don't recommend to convert it into a string (unless it is something like a serial number that is not treated as an actual number).

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version compared to Dean's

```
Sub StrLength()
Dim i As Long, str As String

str = "136"
i = Len(str)

StrLength = String(ExpectedLength - Len(str), "0") & str

End Sub
```

Small subroutines as these can easily be used as [Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement), where you call the function in a regular sub. For example, when you are looping through a range of cells:

```
Function StrLength(str As String, ExpectedLength As Long) As String
Dim i As Long

i = Len(str)

StrLength = String(ExpectedLength - Len(str), "0") & str

End Function


Sub Test()
Dim c As Range

For each c In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:B200")
    If Len(c.Value) < 5 Then c.Value = StrLength(Str:=c.Value, ExpectedLength:=5)
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Note that this is the slowest idea you can have and will convert the number into a (mabye) usless string (no calculations with this anymore). Also you might want to have a look into `String(ExpectedLength - Len(str), "0")` to get rid of your loops.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ noted and edited!